# issue with custom loginwebapi in blazor server app(use built in webapi framework)

Tags: c#, postman, blazor, blazor-server-side, webapi

I create server side proect(blazor server app) and then use webapi built in framework

I created a custom webapi for login in blazor sever side

see my code:

```
namespace CrudBlazorServerApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
     public class EmpsController : ControllerBase
     {
        private readonly sqldbcontext _context;

        public EmpsController(sqldbcontext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        
        //if i am comment PostEmp method then below method(checkLogin) work fine problem is both method not work at a time
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Emp>> PostEmp(Emp emp)
        {
            _context.emps.Add(emp);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetEmp", new { id = emp.empid }, emp);
        }

        //if i am comment checklogin method then above method(postemp) work fine
        //custom login webapi
        //[HttpPost]
        //[Consumes("application/json")]
        //public Emp checkLogin(string username, string password)
        //{
        //    Emp hasemp = _context.emps.Where(e => e.username == username & e.password == password).FirstOrDefault();
        //    return hasemp;
        //}
```

[if i comment checklogin method then postemp work fine see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqUPh.png) **201-created**

[if i uncomment checklogin method then postemp not work see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z50H7.png) **204-NoContent**

why both webapi(postemp and checklogin) not work at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because both methods have same endpoint. Because your route configuration is `[Route("api/[controller]")]` and your Actions are marked as `[HttpPost]` which means your endpoints will be as `api/Emps` and not `api/Emps/PostEmp` or `api/Emps/checkLogin`

So you will need to change to one of the below to make it work:

Option 1:

Change your route to `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` and then your endpoints will be `api/Emps/PostEmp` or `api/Emps/checkLogin`

Option 2:

Change your HttpPost to pass the template as `[HttpPost("PostEmp")]` and `[HttpPost("checkLogin")]` *(these names can be changed to whatever you like without changing the method names)*

Comment: perfectly work your suggestion in my project and postman tool